# How to encode 256bit AES key using base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using NodeJS to interact with Amazon Web Services (specifically s3).  I am attempting to use [Server side encryption with customer keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html).  Only AES256 is allowed as an encryption method.  The API specifies that the keys be base64 encoded.

At the moment I am merely testing the AWS api, I am using throwaway test files, so security (and secure key generation) are not an issue at the moment.

My problem is as follows: Given that I am in posession of a 256bit hexadecimal string, how do I obtain a base64 encoded string of the integer that that represents?

My first instinct was to first parse the Hexadecimal string as an integer, and convert it to a string using `toString(radix)` specifying a radix of 64.  However `toString()` accepts a maximum radix of 36.  Is there another way of doing this?

And even if I do this, is that a base64 encoded string of 256bit encryption key?  The API reference just says that it expects a key that is ["appropriate for use with the algorithm specified"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html). (I am using the putObject method).

Comment: That question adresses encoding the string.  I want to encode an integer.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a hex string to a base64 string in node.js, you can very easily use a Buffer;

```
var key_in_hex = '11223344556677881122334455667788'
var buf = new Buffer(key_in_hex, 'hex')
var str = buf.toString('base64')
```

...which will set `str` to the base64 equivalent of the hex string passed in ('112233...')

You could also of course combine it to a one liner;

```
var key_in_hex = '11223344556677881122334455667788'
var str = new Buffer(key_in_hex, 'hex').toString('base64')
```